# Accessing json array elements?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

```
var myobj = {
              "date": "24062014",
              "class" : "a",
              "student details" : [
                  {
                    "student name" : "xyz"
                    "studentid"   : "a1"
                    "student marks": {
                        "maths" : "50"
                        "science" : "60"
                 }
              },
                {
                    "student name" : "tyr"
                    "studentid"   : "a2"
                    "student marks": {
                        "maths" : "40"
                        "science" : "50"
                 }
               } 
              ]
            }
```

questions :

1. how to access maths marks or science marks ?
2. how to display in the form of

   ```
         someid - student name {      
                         "studentname" :"somename "
                          "marks"     : "somemarks "
                         }
   ```
3. Can all the above mentioned format for students can be saved into mongodb ? if yes, how can we save each iteration to db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, and looks like a poorly worded rewrite of a homework question but see if this helps you any:

```
var _ = require('lodash')

var studentsByID = {};

_.each(myobj["student details"], function (student) {
    studentsByID[student.studentid] = {
       studentname: student["student name"],
       marks: _.values(student["student marks"])
    };
});

console.log(studentsByID);
```

With regard to saving the objects to the database as documents, yes, of course they can be saved.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    async = require('async');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;

  var collection = db.collection('students');

  async.map(
    studentsByID,
    function (studentDetails, doneInserting) {
      collection.insert(studentDetails, doneInserting);
    },
    function (err, results) {
      console.log(err, results);
      db.close();
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: sorry, if it made difficult to understand though your answer is excellent!! worked perfect :)